# NatValidationError when deploying an archetype contract with taquito

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, archetype

I am attempting to deploy a very simple archetype contract with Taquito in a react Dapp. However, I am receiving a validation error. My guess is that I have the syntax wrong for the storage parameter, but I cannot figure out what it should be.

This error is being caught in this function:

```
const deployContract = async () => {
ttk.wallet.originate({
  code: testJSON,
  storage: {
    res: 0
  },
})
.send()
.then((originationOp) => {
  console.log(`Waiting for confirmation of origination...`);
  return originationOp.contract();
})
.then((contract) => {
  console.log(`Origination completed for ${contract.address}.`);
})
.catch((error) => console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));
}
```

Where `ttk` is Tezos Toolkit and `wallet` is a beaconWallet. (This part of the code is copied from archetype docs)

I have the error:

```
Error: {
  "value": {
    "res": 0
  },
  "token": {
    "val": {
      "prim": "nat"
    },
    "idx": 0
  },
  "name": "NatValidationError",
  "message": "[0] Value is not a number: [object Object]"
```

The contract:

```
archetype simple

variable res : nat = 0

entry exec (n : nat) {
  res := n
}
```

The michelson/JSON input:

```
javascript
export const code = [
  { prim: 'storage', args: [{ prim: 'nat' }] },
  { prim: 'parameter', args: [{ prim: 'nat', annots: ['%exec'] }] },
  {
    prim: 'code',
    args: [
      [
        { prim: 'UNPAIR' },
        { prim: 'DUP' },
        {
          prim: 'DIP',
          args: [
            { int: '1' },
            [
              { prim: 'DIG', args: [{ int: '1' }] },
              { prim: 'DROP', args: [{ int: '1' }] },
            ],
          ],
        },
        { prim: 'DUG', args: [{ int: '1' }] },
        { prim: 'DROP', args: [{ int: '1' }] },
        { prim: 'NIL', args: [{ prim: 'operation' }] },
        { prim: 'PAIR' },
      ],
    ],
  },
]
```

I have tried inputing {"int" : "0"} in the storage and a few other less likely variations but I am now well and truly stuck

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-- EDIT --

The required syntax here is: `storage: 0`.

When a contract run through the archetype compiler has only a single nat in storage, the storage parameter to the originate method takes a single value.

When a contract run through the archetype archetype compiler has more than one item in storage, then the storage parameter takes an object. For example this contract...

```
archetype simple

variable res : nat = 0
variable ser: nat = 1

entry exec (n : nat) {
  res := n
}
```

... will be initialised by a storage object:

```
const deployContract = async () => {
ttk.wallet.originate({
  code: testJSON,
  storage: {
    res: 0,
    ser: 1
  }
//.send().then(...etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the storage is a `nat`, Taquito expects a number as the storage (not an object):

```
ttk.wallet.originate({
  code: testJSON,
  storage: 0,
})
```

I imagine Archetype would give a name to the storage because it is represented as a variable, but if you explore the generated Michelson, you can see that the storage is a single `nat` value with no annotation:

```
{ prim: 'storage', args: [{ prim: 'nat' }] }
```

Comment: Thanks Claude I figured out what was going on via your answer. Turns out that Taquito usually does expect objects as storage for nats, but in the edge case of only a single nat item in the storage, it expects a number.

Comment: This is not exactly true, Taquito expects a number if the storage is a number :) A JavaScript object is only expected as the initial storage when the Michelson type of the storage is a `pair`.

Comment: Hey Claude thanks for this feedback - I wasn't quite clear. You can see in the example solution I posted below that in the case where there are two nats in storage, the Originate `storage` parameter accepts an object with two key-value pairs (which assign each nat to a number).e.g `storage: {natOne : 0, natTwo: 1}`. However if there is only one nat in storage, Taquito will not accept an object with a single key-value pair (which is what I would have expected). Instead it accepts just a number. That is, it accepts `storage: 0` but **not** `storage : { natOne: 0}`

Comment: The problem with using a high-level language that compiles to Michelson without knowing Michelson is that it abstracts a lot of things that are actually important. There are **never** 2 `nats` in the storage of a contract, the storage is **always** a single value. I would really recommend you read the Michelson documentation, at least to have some perspective about what Archetype does and how Taquito interacts with the code on-chain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - there is a lot to learn and this has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

The required syntax here is: `storage: 0`.

When a contract run through the archetype compiler has only a single nat in storage, the `storage` parameter to the originate method takes a single value.

When a contract run through the archetype archetype compiler has more than one item in storage, then the `storage` parameter takes an object. For example this contract...

```
archetype simple

variable res : nat = 0
variable ser: nat = 1

entry exec (n : nat) {
  res := n
}
```

... will be initialised by a storage *object*:

```
const deployContract = async () => {
ttk.wallet.originate({
  code: testJSON,
  storage: {
    res: 0,
    ser: 1
  }
//.send().then(...etc....
```

Comment: Once again, this is not exactly true, it has nothing to do with being a rational number or not, a pair can hold a `string` and a `nat` or even 2 `big_map`! It has everything to do with the way Archetype syntax abstracts what's really going on in Michelson. 
Also, these are not `variable names` but `annotations`, they are completely optional in Michelson, but quite useful in general.

Comment: Okay I've removed my commentary about the michelson which I clearly need to read up on and restricted my answer to the descriptive facts and what I had to do to solve the problem.